# Can not run hbase standalone in my mac

Tags: hbase

I follow the instruction of this quickstart, but fail to run hbase standalone in my pc. Could anyone help on this ? Thanks

http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html

Here's logs:

```
2014-01-13 13:15:01,667 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: clean znode for master, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to get data of znode /hbase/master
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getDataNoWatch(ZKUtil.java:777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MasterAddressTracker.deleteIfEquals(MasterAddressTracker.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZNodeClearer.clear(ZNodeClearer.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2779)
2014-01-13 13:15:01,669 ERROR [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: clean znode for master, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getDataNoWatch(ZKUtil.java:777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MasterAddressTracker.deleteIfEquals(MasterAddressTracker.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZNodeClearer.clear(ZNodeClearer.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2779)
2014-01-13 13:15:01,669 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker: Can't get or delete the master znode
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.getData(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.getDataNoWatch(ZKUtil.java:777)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MasterAddressTracker.deleteIfEquals(MasterAddressTracker.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZNodeClearer.clear(ZNodeClearer.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2779)
```

hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///var/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/var/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

 <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2181</value>
  </property>

 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

hbase-env.sh

```
export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

Comment: Are you trying to run via command line,if so then you need to add the following `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=\`/usr/bin/hbase classpath\`` . This is what i needed to type in linux i dont know regarding mac

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: `quorum=localhost:2181`..This is wrong. You need to specify the quorum as the machine's host name. Your cluster isn't able to connect to zookeeper

Comment: @Jijo, this is standalone mode, so localhost should be OK

Comment: Try specifying the host name in the configuration xml because in the last part of stack trace it is clearly noted that your cluster can't get or delete zookeeper node `2014-01-13 13:15:01,669 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker: Can't get or delete the master znode`

Comment: @Jijo Still the same error, even after I add the following to hbase-site.xml   <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
    <description>The directory shared by RegionServers.
    </description>
  </property>

Comment: Can you share your hbase-site.xml and hbase-env.sh

Comment: @Jijo, I have updated the post with hbase-site.xml and hbase-env.sh

Comment: Add this to hbase-env.sh `export HBASE_CLASSPATH=\`echo $HBASE_CLASSPATH | sed -e "s|$ZOOKEEPER_CONF:||"\``

Comment: @Jijo  unfortunately, still the same error.

Comment: did you start your zookeeper server ?? and then hbase master and then your region server?

Comment: @Jijo, according the instruction of this page http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html， it looks like I don't need to start zookeeper server separately, I just invoke command start-hbase.sh

Comment: Well for the hbase master to work zookeeper must be started!!

Comment: I think hbase is supposed to start its own zookeeper in standalone mode.

Answer (score 0):

try jps command on command line to figure if your services are running
You should see Zookeeper, HBMaster and HBRegionServer there

then I would get rid of the

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/var/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
```

this defaults to safe values if you don't have it and somehow your ZK may be confused with this path. Especially you are not clear if you use a MAC of a PC, you mention both. Physical paths are using the C:\xxx\ notation on PC but file:///xxxxx/ on mac and linux.

Answer (score 0):

HBase stand alone starts it's own zookeeper (if you run `start-hbase.sh), but it if fails to start or keep running, the other need hbase daemons won't work.

Make sure you explicitly set the properties for your interface `lo0` in the `hbase-site.xml` file:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.dns.interface</name>
  <value>lo0</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.dns.interface</name>
  <value>lo0</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.master.dns.interface</name>
  <value>lo0</value>
</property>
```

I found that specifically when my wifi was on, if these entries were missing, zookeeper filed to start.

Answer (score -1):

I also received this error. I found that even if shell starts it doesn't mean you have server running, you still need to run `start-hbase.sh` manually to start server.